# "SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax" but it worked before! (Python 3.5.2 doing a tutorial for beginners)

Tags: python

Soo I swear this code worked before!

## Is there a setting on IDLE that I might have accidently turned on?

I'm trying to do something very simple..set variables.

As you can see these work:

```
>>> print("hello")
hello



>>> def main():
        print("hey")


>>>main()
hey
```

So when I try to recreate an example problem, you would expect these variables to work, right?

```
def main():
    print("This calculates the cost of coffee.")
    print()
    n = eval(input("Enter amount of coffee in pounds: ")
    m = 10.50 * n
     
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why??? Why does Python 3.5.2 return "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"?

Thanks guys! Sorry I'm such a noob.

Comment: You are missing a closing parentheses at the end of this line: `n = eval(input("Enter amount of coffee in pounds: ")`. So you need this: `n = eval(input("Enter amount of coffee in pounds: ")))`

Comment: Pro-tip - Do not use eval. There is always a better way to do it without using eval. You look like you want to convert it to an int/float. So do that instead: `float(input("Enter amount of coffee in pounds: "))`

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis in line 4 at the end `n = ...)`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments several times, You are simply missing a closing `)` on line 4 of your program. line 4 should look like

`n = eval(input("Enter amount of coffee in pounds: "))# <--extra parenthesis`

---

Some unrelated points in your code:

- Why are you using `eval()`? It looks like your going for float/integer conversion, so use `int()` or `float()`.
- Instead of adding a extra print to achieve a newline, simply say `print("This calculates the cost of coffee.\n")`
- The last two lines of your program can be condensed into a single statement: `n = float(input("Enter amount of coffee in pounds: "))*10.50`

---

After adding my suggestions to your code, it would yield something like this:

```
def main():
    print("This calculates the cost of coffee.\n")
    n = float(input("Enter amount of coffee in pounds: "))*10.50
```